# Logarithm in the exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, contest-math

> $$(2x)^{\log 2} = (3y)^{\log 3} \\
> 3^{\log x} = 2^{\log y}$$
>
> Solve for $x$ and $y$.

My intuition for solving such problems is taking the logarithm on both sides but it does not work. I also tried using the swap rule by taking the base of the exponent and swapping it in the logarithm, but I am not able to do it.

(P.S. This is not a homework question. It is from the previous question papers of a math contest.)

Comment: Taking log on both sides is the right approach. Where are you stuck?

Comment: So i come to a stage where log2 log2x=log3log3y;log3logx =logylog2

Comment: After this i dont know how to manipulate the equations

Comment: Do you know $\log(3y)=\log(3)+\log(y)$?

Comment: Yea i am aware of that

Comment: So you have a system of linear equation of the form $ax+by=c,dx+ey=f$. Solve this is not hard. Then exponent log x and log y to get x and y.

Comment: Is x =2,y=3 the correct answer

Comment: $x = e^{\ln x} $  so $x^{\ln 2} = e^{\ln 2 *\ln x}=2^{\ln x} $. That'll probably help.

Comment: Mathematica says $x= 2^{-\frac{1}{\log (6)}},y= 3^{-\frac{1}{\log
   (6)}}$. Also to test something is correct you can substitute into the equation.

Comment: But try plugging in x = 1/2 ,y = 1/3,It works

Comment: @TSidharth: See my last edit. Which of the versions of equation $(1)$ did you mean? The current or the original?

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER:** I posted this answer when the first equation read $2x^{\log 2}=3y^{\log 3}$ without parenthesis, but I see that that has been changed to $(2x)^{\log 2}=(3y)^{\log 3}$ in which case my answer below does not fit the problem. For this new equation $(1)$ it becomes
$$
as-bt=b^2-a^2
$$
leading through the same steps as below to
$$
s=-a\quad t=-b
$$
so that $x=\frac12$ and $y=\frac13$.

---

Define $a=\log2,b=\log3,s=\log x$, and $t=\log y$. Then the first equation becomes
$$
a+as=b+bt\\
\iff\\
as-bt=b-a\tag 1
$$
and the second equation becomes
$$
bs=at\tag 2
$$
Multiplying $(1)$ by $b$ we get
$$
abs-b^2t=b(b-a)
$$
and using $(2)$ on the LHS then yields
$$
a^2t-b^2t=b(b-a)
$$
and since $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ we can divide by this on both sides to have
$$
t=-\frac b{a+b}
$$
so that
$$
\log y=-\frac{\log 2}{\log 6}
$$

---

A similar process started by multiplying $(1)$ by $a$ leads to
$$
s=-\frac{a}{a+b}\iff\log x=-\frac{\log 3}{\log 6}
$$
which after applying anti-logs should give you
$$
x=\frac1{\sqrt[\log 6]3}=3^{-\frac1{\log 6}}\quad\text{ and }\quad y=\frac1{\sqrt[\log 6]2}=2^{-\frac1{\log 6}}
$$
or however you want to format those results.